# MIPS: Check the winning condition of a 5x5 tic-tac-toe game

Tags: algorithm, tic-tac-toe

I am new to coding in general and MIPS in specific.
I have a MIPS project in class to make a 5x5 tic-tac-toe game with the winning condition being that there are 3 consecutive points in diagonal, vertical or horizontal. From the examples from the internet, most people make cases to check the winning condition but for a large 5x5 board that approach is impossible. My question is, is there any way to check the winning condition for this program and I have another question: is it better to make the player input the number of rows and columns that they want to pick or just pick the square based on their numerical order. Thank for answering.

Comment: These two questions should be separated into two different posts, @Brahhdon.
For the first question, please post the code for the game, showing what you've tried so far.
The second question should be asked in a game theory stack exchange, or similar.

Comment: Two questions here, one needs code and the other needs a different stack exchange.

Comment: "most people make cases to check the winning condition but for a large 5x5 board that approach is impossible" -- why do you say this?  There's 25 positions on the board, and ~50 ways to make 3 consecutive.  What is impossible about that?

Comment: There is nothing specific to MIPS or assembly in this question, so really there is no good reason to tag it MIPS.